# Add simple Excel formula for progression calculations

Tags: excel, vba, regression

I would like to do these two computations which I thought I should do by a simple formulae in a cell. However, I am getting nowhere with that thought so far!

I want to save $1 incrementally for one year. How much should I end up with at the end of the year? That is:

1 Jan: $1,
2 Jan: $2,
3 Jan: $3,
...,
31 Dec: ?,
Total: ??

The other saving method is double what was saved previous day. That is:
1 Jan: $1,
2 Jan: $2,
3 Jan: $4,
...,
31 Dec: ?,
Total: ??

I though there should be a way to put a formula in a single cell so that when I change the variables (eg, number of days, amount, or increment by addition or multiplication) I should get the total.

I hope I am not overthinking for excel... :)

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the answer for saving $1 more per day will be $66795 in a 365-day year.  (365 * (365+1) / 2)  And for saving double each day it will be $75,153,362,648,762,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 (not an exact number - just what Excel displays).  (i.e. 2^365-1)

Comment: P.S.  If you do decide to personally save some money using the second method, I want 1% commission for having told you how much it will be!! ;)

Comment: You've heard of the old fable of the [rice and chessboard](http://www.singularitysymposium.com/exponential-growth.html), right? If you can double the previous days' savings ...then frankly, you don't need to save in the first place, you're doing quite well.  The first one (saving a dollar incrementally) is just `(365*(365+1))/2`

Comment: Of course, @YowE3K :)
I thought there was some =Progression formula or so. But thanks, that is a clever formula! And the doubling was probably OK initially, until I got to 20 times!! Thanks to you both!